# Time showing in recent tabs when it is opened

Tags: android-studio, time, tabs

I want to know when was the last app opened in my recent tab and closed .
The recent tab has some features which show last time it opened and it updates every time it opened .
So what code it need and how to make changes

If i use Android studio then how do i do